# what is wrong with this Instagram API call?

Tags: javascript, npm, request, instagram

What is wrong with this code? I want to pull my hair out! I'm getting JSON from the Instagram API. console logging just body gives me the JSON, but when I do something like body.data or body.pagination, I get nothing! Help please and thank you.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app     = express(),
    https   = require("https"),
    fs      = require("fs"),
    request = require("request");

request("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=xxxxx&scope=public_content&count=1", function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)      // returns all the relevant JSON
        console.log(body.data) // **returns undefined!!!!!**
    }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./test.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body` is literally what it says on the tin - the body of the HTTP response. In other words, it's a string - you need to run it through `JSON.parse` to actually access it as an object.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body).data);
```

Obviously, if you were going to use this for real, you'd assign the parsed object to a variable rather than running it every time you access it.